# Why is my html, returned by a shortcode, not being executed as html?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Hi I am fairly new to php and started messing around with some shortcode. I created a quick shortcode that returns a string that contains html in it. I expected it to be executed by the browser. Almost all of it gets executed properly except for a link that actually gets printed out like

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

Here is my shortcode I wrote

```
            add_shortcode('booklist_jumbo','generate_booklist_jumbo');
            //[booklist_jumbo]
            function generate_booklist_jumbo($atts) 
            {
                $a = shortcode_atts( array(
                'category' => 'Upcoming',
                'name' => '',
                'list_order' => 'DESC'
                ), $atts );

                $bookOrder = $a[book_order];
                $listOrder = $a[list_order];

                if($a[name] !== '') {
                    $name = $a[name];
                    $second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, "saic3_LibraryIndex", DB_HOST);
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `LibraryList` WHERE `list_name` = %s ORDER BY date_created $listOrder LIMIT 1";
                    $booklist = $second_db->get_results( $second_db->prepare( $query, $name) );
                }
                else if($a[category] !== "") {
                    $cat = $a[category];
                    $second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, "saic3_LibraryIndex", DB_HOST);
                    $query = "SELECT ll.* FROM LibraryListCategory llc INNER JOIN LibraryListCategoryList llcl ON llc.category_id = llcl.fk_category_id INNER JOIN LibraryList ll ON llcl.fk_list_id = ll.list_id WHERE llc.name= %s ORDER BY ll.date_created $listOrder LIMIT 1";
                    $booklist = $second_db->get_results( $second_db->prepare($query, $cat) );
                }
                if ($booklist!=null) {
                        $booklist[0]->list_name = stripslashes($booklist[0]->list_name);
                        $code = strval($booklist[0]->list_type_code);
                        $msg = stripslashes($booklist[0]->banner_msg);
                        $msg = str_replace("\\n", "<br>", $msg);
                        switch($code) {
                            case "1": $link = "/booklist-details/".$booklist[0]->fk_list_id; break;
                            case "2": $link = "/booklist-dvd-details/".$booklist[0]->fk_list_id; break;
                            case "3": $link = "/booklist-audio-details/".$booklist[0]->fk_list_id; break;
                        }
                        $content = '<div class="bootstrap-container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="jumbotron container-fluid" style="height: 600px; width: 100%; background: url('.$booklist[0]->image_url.') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">';
                        $content.= '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" ><h2 class="book-feat-title center-block">'.$booklist[0]->list_name.'</h2></a><p class="book-feat-msg">'.$msg.'</p>';    
                        $content.= '</div></div></div></div>';
                    }
                else {
                    $content="<h4>no booklist records</h4>";
                }

                $second_db->close();
                return $content;

            }
```

Everything works as expected except for the banner message that is wrapped in a p tag...I have tried looking up anything similar but can't seem to find anything. I am guessing it has something to do with it being considered a string rather than html but I am not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: can you please share screenshot for issue as its very hard to understand what you want

Comment: @Jaydp just added.

Answer (score 0):

Please add one more line for `$msg`

```
$msg = str_replace("\\n", "<br>", $msg);
$msg = add_filter( 'the_content', $msg );
```

Comment: Can you explain this? add_filter is supposed to take a callback correct? What is 'the_content' supposed to contain. This is also a dynamic message so I need a way to get the html to execute no matter what it contains.